# SmartTV connected to a Client Bridge mode Router is invisible to the network

Tags: tv, bridge-router, smart-tv

I have a Samsung SmartTV (UE40D5700) and I want to connect it to the internet. Since it has no built-in WiFi, the only commercial option Samsung gives is to buy their own wifi bundle (70$) (no other WiFi USB works).

I have a D-Link Access Point which works as client mode and the internet works fine. The problem comes when I try to use DLNA/NAS software to stream media to my TV or even using the offical Samsung remote iPhone app: the TV is visible in the network for a while and then it disappears and I have to set up the connection again (TV) to make it visible, which is quite annoying, specially if you're streaming a movie or music to your TV.

I had a TP-Link router unused so I decided to install DD-WRT and use it as a Client Bridge. This works fine, my TV has connection to the internet with no problem at all, but now it is even worse: It is not visible at all, not even for a while.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong – but I certainly know that there must be a configuration problem in the router somehow.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 3):

I may not have a full solution, but have a similar setup and a similar problem, which might point to the right direction.

I use a Speedport W500v wireless router as client bridge to connect my Samsung UE46EH5450 to the wifi network which is provided by a FRITZ!Box 3270.
That FRITZ!Box has a built in NAS feature, with a 500GB WD harddrive connected, which stores my media. 
Right after the TVs start the FritzNAS is visible in the TVs sources and also my PC which is conneted to the same Wifi, shows up.

Suddenly the Samsung TV seems to lose contact to those network resources, when I'm browsing files or streaming a video from one of the network resources. It says "Connection lost" or something (in german for me). This happens at different times after startup, sometimes a video plays like half an hour before the connection is lost, sometimes right after startup while still browsing through files. No definite time here.

I tried another thing:
I downloaded "Samsung AllShare" to my pc, a program which allows sharing media to other Samsung devices (such as mobile phones, tablets, tvs) from a pc. 
I was able to stream files from the NAS to the TV. The quite indirect way via pc with SamsungAllShare installed, is of course not a perfect solution for me.
Also, AllShare doesn't always recognize the TV as possible output device, the TV seems to disappear from the network, too!

I have to say, that using the TVs browser does work fine, and in the routers network overview the TV is listed and can be pinged.

So it looks like, that the TV doesn't like the wireless bridge setup. I'll try and set up a cable connection to verify.

Good luck,
Slash

Answer (score 0):

Even if Samsung TV writes that it cannot connect to the Internet, try using the Smart HUB - the Internet works in applications.